# Werewolves and Barbers

Tags: shapeshifters

At the barber, I was contemplating that most animals don’t need haircuts. A squirrel, for example, can't cut its hair and doesn’t need to. It would be quite debilitating if animal’s hair needed to be cut!

Only humans and [dogs need barbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_grooming#Hair_removal).  Not cats, usually.

So what about werewolves? Wolves are “normal” in not needing haircuts, but dogs acquired the need when they started evolving to live with us.

Humans are not chimps (or our common ancestor which was very chimp-like). So would the transformed **man** be a **wild** wolf?  Or would a transformed modern human actually be more like a dog, with a mix of genes that are not selected for by pure wild living, but in the contest of living among humans and as part of civilization?

A wild wolf that developed a mutation so that the hair kept growing would be at an extreme disadvantage and would die out. But among humans, with barbers available, it's not a problem and any advantages it conveys would be available. At least it would be neutral.

Consider ways in which modern humans are different from other apes. Loss of chewing muscles and a reliance on cooked food due to simplified digestive system, loss of strength but gain in precision of motor control. That all goes with the context of how we live and become advantages.

So, **would werewolves be more dog-like?**  Maybe not any breed we recognise, but evolved to live in the niche of human civilization and perhaps possessing traits that *require* human help to manage?

And in the specific case of hair, will the haircut be specific to the form, so a man with a haircut and shaved beard (or a woman with shaved legs) will *not* show the modification in the canid state?  Each state will need to get its own haircuts, not shown in the other form!  Would he expect a discount to get both haircuts back to back at a single appointment?

Comment: Haircut? Maybe.  Eyebrow trim?  Oh, yeah.

Answer (score 12):

First of all, humans don't *need* haircuts.  We get them for cultural reasons, but human hair, like animal fur, has a maximum length; each hair will fall out after growing for a certain amount of time.  The exact length will vary from person to person, but it generally won't reach the point where it becomes a health hazard (unless you regularly get into fights or crawl through thick foliage where it can be grabbed or entangled).

Modern humans probably have longer hair than we once did, since we don't have to deal with fights or trees that much and culturally many people find long hair attractive - possibly *because* of its potential hazards in the wild, like a peacock's tail - but with a few notable exceptions it won't generally reach the point where you are tripping over it if you don't cut it.  The only animals that *need* haircuts are those that have been purposely bred by humans for impractically long hair; sheep and some show dogs for instance.

My guess is that werewolves would have no more need for haircuts than humans or wolves.  Assuming that their fur length in wolf form is based on separate genes than their hair length in human form, and unless someone was deliberately *breeding* werewolves to have the impractically long hair of show sheepdogs or poodles (unlikely), they probably wouldn't have overly long fur and wouldn't need haircuts.

Where it gets interesting is if the genes for human-form hair length and wolf-form fur length are linked.  Since modern humans tend to have longer hair than most wild animals, a long-haired human transforming into wolf form might result in much longer hair than a normal wolf would or should have, and while long human hair is a mostly harmless ornament, transforming into a furball covered in long hair would be seriously debilitating to a wolf (and probably not particularly attractive either) causing the gene to be selected against.  This would mean that werewolves in human form might have *shorter* hair than non-werewolves.

On the other hand, if the genes for wolf-form head hair are linked to genes for human-form head hair, but the genes for wolf-form body hair are separate, you could wind up with wolf-form werewolves having long manes on their head, retained from the longer human head-hair.  Since manes aren't that debilitating (and look cool, so that's a plus for sexual selection) this would probably be selected for.

Depending on the culture and the specific details of your story, it might or might not be considered culturally acceptable for werewolves to be well-groomed.  A lot will depend on details that you haven't spelled out, like how intelligent the werewolves are and whether or not they are seen as accepted members of human society, or whether they have their own werewolf-culture.

Comment: Eating is difficult if I don’t trim the hair above my upper lip.  Covering the ears might be useful in cold climatee. But covering the eyes (when I was young) would be a hazard.  Hmm, maybe that’s a reason for male pattern baldness?

Comment: @JDługosz The reason behind male pattern baldness isn't well understood but there are a few theories.  It may be (A) a side effect of high testosterone in early life and therefore an indicator of being able to produce strong male children, (B) a sign of age, and therefore the maturity and experience that can make a good father figure, or (C) just a biological fluke that wasn't strongly selected against.  Worth noting: surveys show that, all else being equal, women on average find full baldness just as as appealing as full hair (but nobody likes wispy hair or comb-overs).

Comment: I recall cases that show that triggering male pattern baldness is due to testosterone. But *why* is the mechanism there? So reason A and others are not the same kind of thing to list as alternatives.  But my earlier observation is that the first effects as a young adult is that the receeding hairline would no longer block the eyes so much if one never cut the hair.

Comment: @JDługosz The problem of hair falling over your eyes goes away once it's long enough, no cutting involved. It's only a period of maybe half a year when you are growing it out that it's annoying. Concerning beard, it's a little more difficult to eat *in a sociably acceptable* way, but with practice that's possible too. I actually only recently started trimming the beard on my upper lift (for aesthetic reasons) and could eat perfectly well before that - I admit ice in a cone was horror, but most foods are okay.

Comment: I figure male baldness is much like darkening of the genitals. A side effect that isn't harmful enough to select against. Long hair is also a sign of health generally. Practically all (primitive) cultures treasure long hair. But quite a few remove body hair, notably most native american tribes in North America.

Answer (score 5):

It might depend on the type of werewolf. The classical werewolf of lore is much more a true mix of human and wolf than is the newer, Twilight version (which I believe was later identified merely as a shapeshifter, not a werewolf, however, as the question might also pertain to shapeshifters, I will address it as well). The main difference between the two models is the degree of separation between the wolf and human halves.

In the classical lore, the individual is primarily human except at the full moon when he morphs into a half-human, half-wolf mongrel. One might almost say that such a werewolf is only 1/4 wolf, thus possibly expressing traits with only 1/4 the power. If that is the case, the mongrel form (assuming the morphed werewolf wished to look his best while on his killing spree) would probably need a haircut. It seems rather unlikely that a creature that only really exists on the full moon would grow enough hair to require a haircut, but I suppose it's possible. It seems safe to assume that the werewolf, while in human form, and thus expressing human traits, would require regular shearing.

In the world of shapeshifters, particularly wolf/human shifters, the separation between the human and wolf sides is much more distinct. Instead of displaying a mash of both human and wolf characteristics, the shapeshifter displays one at a time, meaning that, as a wolf, he would probably not need his fur trimmed. As a man,  he would likely require haircuts. Again, it seems unlikely that, even if the wolf wanted a haircut, a barber would oblige.

In either case, as I understand the lore, the transformation from human to wolf/wolf-man requires more hair than simply that which is found on the human. Both classical and new-age mythologies portray the wolf form of the werewolf/shifter as being much hairier than the human form, so the creature must grow more hair during the transformation. That means that thousands of follicles go active very quickly, producing massive amounts of keratin in moments. For some reason, this process is quickly stopped after the transformation is complete, leaving us no Rapunzel-esque masses of excess hair. That means that there must be something about the act of shifting that sends the follicles into hyper-drive. On the flip side, when the wolf transforms back into a human, all the extra hair disappears, leaving only what was there originally. Now, I don't believe there is a workable scientific explanation for all the effects of either style of werewolf, and most lore bases the transformations in magic or spirituality or some such, so, going with a magic/religious/unexplained transformation, what happens to one form shouldn't affect the other in terms of hair or nails. Naturally, we would expect injuries to carry over, but superficial things like the hair would be assumed to remain with the form. For the purposes of identification, it is possible that dyeing the hair might transfer, but that depends on the type of magic/religion/other, as well as the intent.

If it was a spell, the human's haircut might affect the length of the wolf's fur, but probably not really accurately. A person with long hair might turn into a wolf with longer hair, but a person with a mowhawk probably wouldn't turn into a wolf with one strip of long hair along its back and a woman who shaved her legs almost certainly wouldn't turn into a wolf that was bald from the hips down. If it was some kind of spiritual same-soul-two-bodies thing then one form shouldn't affect the other at all.

In the classical style, the creature morphs without conscious thought, sometimes against his will, and loses his ability to ration while morphed, suggesting a heavier biological base of explanation. If the wolf part of the creature takes over, then eventually recedes again taking with it only what if brought, then the two forms should affect one another. If the human is bald (as a baseline example), he will grow x inches of hair. If the human has long hair, he would be expected to still grow x inches of hair because the transformation process doesn't know and doesn't care how long his hair already is, so if the human has short hair, the mongrel will have short hair, and if the human has long hair, the mongrel will have long hair. When he transforms back, he loses x inches of hair, returning him to his pretransformation state. If at some point during his time as a mongrel the werewolf were sedated and his hair cut, the transfomation process would still take back x inches of hair, leaving the resulting human with shorter hair.

I highly doubt that any barber would give a discount that *encouraged* werewolves to return to his shop, no matter how dedicated a customer the werewolf might be. You might be able to work something out with a local groomer.

Also, most, if not all, breeds of domesticated dogs do not need haircuts. Some breeds, such as the poodle, have a standard look that was imposed by humans, thus requiring human maintenance, and some breeds, such as the old english sheepdog, have such long hair that it will quickly mat if not cut, but dogs, like cats, do not continuously grow their hair. Perhaps there is some breed out there that does, but at least the vast majority of breeds do not, so it seems unlikely that a werewolf's wolf half would come from one of those breeds.